# Python pandas, I want to filter by product name and supplier in my product table, and then change the price according to that filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am a new to [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

I want to list it according to the SKU name and process the new column accordingly.

For example, if the SKU name starts with BA, do the following on the bottle price column (bottlePrice*1.30), or if it starts with BF, do the following (bottlePrice*1.10)

I tried a few things but couldn't.

[image]

```
x["bottlePrice"]=x["kdvDahilFiyat"].apply(lambda x: x*3)

#x["NewColumn"]=x[x["SKU"].str.startswith('BA')].apply(lambda x:x*1.20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map a dictionary over the 2 first letters of `sku` column:

```
coeffs = {'BA': 1.3, 'BE': 1.10}
df['NewColumn'] = df['bottlePrice'] * df['sku'].str[:2].map(coeffs).fillna(1)
print(df)

# Output
     sku  bottlePrice  NewColumn
0  BA003      923.940  1201.1220
1  BA009     1306.260  1698.1380
2  BA013     1094.214  1422.4782
3  BE101      977.040  1074.7440
4  BE102     1350.864  1485.9504
5  BE103     2918.730  3210.6030
```

Comment: you helped a lot @corralien. thank you.